# Алгоритм преобразования строк в целые функциями strtol() / strtoll() и их беззнаковыми аналогами

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Меня интересует алгоритм преобразования C-строк в целочисленные типы функциями [`strtol()`, `strtoll()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), [`strtoul()`, `strtoull()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul).

Начнём со стандарта языка C (n1570, 7.22.1.4):

> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions
> `long int strtol(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);`
> [...]
> 5 If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of `base` is zero, the sequence of characters starting with the first digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to the rules of 6.4.4.1. If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of `base` is between 2 and 36, it is used as the base for conversion, ascribing to each letter its value as given above. If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type). A pointer to the final string is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is not a null pointer.
> [...]
> `Returns`
> The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions return the converted value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.

Насколько я понял написанное, идея следующая (ведущие пробельные символы и системы счисления по недесятичному основанию не рассматриваем):

1. В исходной строке отбросим знак минус (если он есть).
2. Если строка хранит число не представимое целевым типом, то *вернём* `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX` и т.д. в зависимости от целевого типа и знака числа в строке. А также установим `errno` в `ERANGE`.
3. Преобразуем строку в целевой тип.
4. Если число в исходной строке начиналось со знака минус, то применим минус к значению в целевом типе.

**Пример №1**

```
errno = 0;
unsigned long long ullval = std::strtoull("-18446744073709551615", nullptr, 10);
cout << "errno:  " << errno   << endl;
cout << "ullval: " << ullval  << endl;

cout << -18446744073709551615ULL << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
errno:  0
ullval: 1
1
```

Пока всё нормально.

1. В строке `"-18446744073709551615"` отбросили знак минус.
2. Число в строке `"18446744073709551615"` представимо типом `unsigned long long`.
3. Преобразуем строку в число.
4. Применяем минус к значению в результирующем типе: `-18446744073709551615ULL == 1ULL`.

**Пример №2**

Аналогичен предыдущему, только преобразуем строку `"-18446744073709551616"`. Вывод:

```
errno:  34
ullval: 18446744073709551615
```

Также получаем ожидаемый вывод.

1. В строке `"-18446744073709551616"` отбросили знак минус.
2. Число в строке `"18446744073709551616"` **не представимо** типом `unsigned long long`. Поэтому изменяем `errno`, и возвращаем `ULLONG_MAX`.

**Пример №3**

```
errno = 0;
long long llval = std::strtoll("-9223372036854775808", nullptr, 10);
cout << "errno: " << errno  << endl;
cout << "llval: " << llval  << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
errno: 0
llval: -9223372036854775808
```

А вот теперь возникают вопросы.

1. В строке `"-9223372036854775808"` отбросили знак минус.
2. Число в строке `"9223372036854775808"` **не представимо** типом `long long`. Поэтому необходимо установить `errno` и вернуть `LLONG_MIN`.

Почему функция `std::strtoll()` вернула `LLONG_MIN`, но не установила `errno`? (ссылки на примеры кода: [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/765e05e27bcd5bda), [clang](https://ideone.com/O2VPZg))

---

Более того следующий код в Visual Studio 2010 (более новой у меня сейчас под рукой нет):

```
errno = 0;
unsigned long ulval = std::strtoul("-4294967296", nullptr, 10);
cout << "errno: " << errno   << endl;
cout << "ulval: " << ulval   << endl;
```

производит следующий вывод:

```
errno: 34
ulval: 1
```

Число в строке `"-4294967296"` после отбрасывания минуса **не представимо** типом `unsigned long`, следовательно должен быть установлен `errno` (что и произошло), и возвращено значение `ULONG_MAX`, но функция вернула `1`.

---

Каков алгоритм преобразования строк в целые функциями `strtol()` / `strtoll()` и их беззнаковыми аналогами в соответствии со стандартом языка. Мои попытки понять написанное в стандарте успехом не увенчались.

---

Хм, кто-то проголосовал за закрытие вопроса с причиной "проблема вызвана опечаткой или не воспроизводится".

Может и стоит закрыть, но прежде, если "проблема не воспроизводится", то хотелось бы увидеть пример компилятора, который выполнив код `std::strtoll("-9223372036854775808", nullptr, 10)`, установит `errno` в ненулевое значение.

Если же `errno` не должен быть установлен, то я с радостью почитаю объяснение, *почему* он не должен быть установлен (со ссылками на стандарт, конечно же).

Comment: *`"Почему функция std::strtoll() вернула LLONG_MIN, но не установила errno?"`* -- на мой вкус, это ошибка. Подозреваю, что такое поведение не меняется по "историческим резонам". Насколько помню, errno устанавливается, если значение не влезает в unsigned соответствующего размера.

Comment: ¿А вас не смущает, что цитата взята из С11, а используется Visual Studio 2010, которая мало того, что вышла до этого стандарта, так еще и работает в режиме С89 + некоторые расширения? В VS2019 такое поведение не наблюдается.

Comment: @user7860670, 1) да, я предполагал, что в более новых версиях поведение может отличаться. 2) Посмотрел [The C89 Draft, 4.10.1.6 The strtoul function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.10.1.6). Принципиальных отличий в плане преобразований от C11 нет.

Comment: См. [Surprising behavior of strtoull(“-1”, NULL, 0) and other negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55052768/2752075).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я видел этот вопрос. И в качестве примера в своём вопросе приводил использование модулярной арифметики `-18446744073709551615ULL == 1ULL`. Вопрос **не в этом**, а в том, почему `std::strtoll("-9223372036854775808", nullptr, 10)` не устанавливает `errno`.

Comment: @wololo, потому что он и не должен: `-9223372036854775808` представимо в `unsigned long long`, поэтом оно и возвращается... здесь всё нормально — ни где не требуется, чтобы число без знака было представимо именно в этом типе...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, 1) ok, почему для проверки представимости используется именно `unsigned long long`, а не `long long`, ведь я использую функцию `strtoll()`, которая преобразует в `long long`? 2) Хотите сказать, что `std::strtoll("9223372036854775810", nullptr, 10)` вернет `9223372036854775810` т.к. это число представимо в `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @wolo, нет ни какой отдельной «проверки на представимость» для которой что-то используется... с т.з. стандарта если результат не представим, то должно быть возвращено LONG_MIN/MAX и установлен `errno`... Как реализация это требование выполнит — дело исключительно её, например, можно просто сделать попытку преобразовать. Если вышли за пределы беззнакового типа — вернули ошибку, не вышли — проверяем помещается ли результат в нужный тип; да — возвращаем; нет — ошибка... хотя на практике обычно делают кое-что немного более хитрое...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, `с т.з. стандарта если результат не представим` Можете детально описать алгоритм с точки зрения стандарта. Потому что я вот чего не понимаю. 1) Есть строка `"-1"` она не представима _беззнаковым типом_. Но это **не** проблема, т.к. в целевой тип преобразуется строка _без минуса_, и только потом происходит отрицание. 2) Теперь преобразуем в _знаковый тип_ строку `LLONG_MIN`. Т.к. алгоритм тот же, то сперва мы должны преобразовать в целевой тип строку `LLONG_MIN` **но без минуса**. Но она **не представима знаковым типом**. Но `errno` не устанавливается.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, "If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, **the value resulting from the conversion is negated (in the return type)**". Вот это мне непонятно. Вроде бы как минус мы должны применять уже _после_ преобразования строки без минуса в целевой тип. И на беззнаковых типах это чётко прослеживается. Но на знаковых типах функция работает как-то не так. Или я чего-то конкретно не понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт не описывает алгоритм, как таковой, он описывает поведение, т.е., в терминах питона, не то как утка устроена, а как она должна крякать; какой должен быть результат при определённых входных значениях (даже если текст и выглядит, как последовательности действий).

На сколько я понимаю фраза из 7.22.1.4/5 «*the value ... is negated (in the return type)*» означает, что для значения полученное при преобразовании `val` результат должен быть эквивалентен `-val` для этого типа. На этом утверждении основывается общепринятая трактовка, что беззнаковые функции, если строка начинается с минуса, должны возвращать значение, к которому применён унарный минус а не ошибку. Да, если основываться только на тексте стандарта, то ИМХО такая трактовка несколько притянута за уши, и не совсем соответствует принципу наименьшего удивления, но так оно сложилось. В манах linux это описано чуть более внятно:

> [**man 3 strtoul**](http://ru.manpages.org/strtoul/3)
>
> Функция `strtoul()` возвращает результат преобразования, либо, если был указан знак минуса, возвращается отрицательный результат преобразования, представленный в виде положительного числа...

Кроме того в *7.22.1.4/5* для всех функций требуется, чтобы если корректное число, заданное в строке выходит за пределы представимых значений типа, то должна возвращаться соответствующая константа и ошибка.

---

И так, `strtoul` должен возвращать (при 32-х битном `long`, `ULONG_MAX==4294967295`):

- Для `-∞`…`-4294967296` → `ULONG_MAX`; `errno=ERANGE`
- Для `-4294967295`…`-1` → `-val`
- Для `0`…`4294967295` → `val`
- Для `4294967296`…`∞` → `ULONG_MAX`; `errno=ERANGE`
- Для, которые невозможно разобрать → 0

А, `strtol` должен возвращать (при `LONG_MIN==-2147483648`, а `LONG_MAX==2147483647`):

- Для `-∞`…`-2147483649` → `LONG_MIN`; `errno=ERANGE`
- Для `-2147483648`…`2147483647` → `val`
- Для `2147483648`…`∞` → `LONG_MAX`; `errno=ERANGE`
- Для строк, которые невозможно разобрать → 0

Аналогично для `strtoull`/`strtoll`.

Каким именно алгоритмом реализации будут реализовывать данное поведение — дело исключительно их. Для примера можно посмотреть реализацию в BSD libc: [`strtoul`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/strtoul.c), [`strtol`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/strtol.c).

---

Все примеры в вопросе соответствуют этим значениям... за исключением msvc, конечно, но он известен тем, что не особо трепетно относится к соответствию стандарту.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в версии FreeBSD описываемая ТС ошибка отсутствует

Comment: @avp, если ты про «Пример №3», то это ИМХО не ошибка... так и должно быть... а причуды msvc — да, отсутствуют...